# iOS 8 Share Extension for specific file format

Tags: ios, objective-c

Let's say I have a .gif file. When I select it and click Share, I want to see my app in App Extension sheet, but ONLY if it has ".gif" filename extension. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See Apple docs at [App Extension Programming](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html) about `NSExtensionActivationRule`.

Basically you need to supply a predicate string for it that excludes any files that don't comply. (This will be easy if there is a `UTType` for .gif, as there is for .PNG (`kUTTypePNG`), but I'm not sure that there is)

Second thing to try would be to reject on filename (if that is possible) else you'll have to accept all `kUTTypeImage` and reject in the extension itself.

I don't think accepting all shares that comply with `kUTTypeImage` but rejecting any that comply with `kUTTypeJPEG` and `kUTTypePNG` would work as a solution, as apps might provide images in several formats, including .gif.